# how to find the most common value in core data attribute

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an attribute that stores 'scores'. I'm wondering how I find out what are the 3 most common scores that have been recorded.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm trying to do the same thing. I've been messing around with NSPredicate but I can't quite figure it out yet.

Answer (score 0):

How many objects are we talking about? A simple approach might be best: fetch all the objects sorted by score and then count the runs of different scores.

Comment: thousands of objects with say unto 200 varying scores. I thought about iterating through the score options, but i wondered if there was a simpler way to do it.